# Pods wordpress form submit button infinitly waiting

Tags: wordpress, podscms

Hi I have a problem in pods framework :--
I made a plugin to update my pod from front end

> $mypods = pods( 'TOWN', $post_id );
>    echo $mypods->form();

problem here is "save change" button is waiting infinitly and not working either.

What point i am missing here ?
What is right code

Comment: Can you please try the latest version of Pods, available at http://Pods.io/latest ? The current version 2.5.1.1 has an issue with form processing, where server-side errors are not reported properly.

Comment: Doing so will probably cause an actual error. I suspect that is because your 're using all caps for your Pod name, but your Pod's name is actually in all lower case. For security reasons we check to make sure that the Pod being edited is the same when the form is generated as when it is processed.

Comment: solution was form() function is getting effected by other tags.So i removed Some Tags.now working fine...........
Thanks JPollock